# WebView on Lollipop uses wrong (desktop scaling). What to do?

Tags: android, android-webview

In my app I have a WebView to show some simple html files. I do that because HTML enables me to apply some formatting, images and so on. On Android version below Lollipop it works ok. The content is displayed as expected.

On Lollipop devices with HD screens on the other hand there is a problem. Text and images are displayed but they are very small. As if WebView would think it is on desktop machine with such a resolution. For better understanding I include a screen snapshot snippet:
[image]

I put my html files in asset folder and display it with:
webView.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/myhtmlfile.htm);
My hrml files have font size defined in css and in pt unit (not px).

I have looked for solution and I have tried many things.

I have set meta tag in my html as per https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have tried various combination setting with this options:

```
webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

I have tried I think all possible combinations of the above.
More puzzling is that sometimes the content is displayed in correct size. I open the activity it is to small. I come to activity at some other time and it is sometimes ok. I have only observed this on a Lollipop devices.
Are there are any other settings I am not aware of?
How to set up webView to display things correctly?

Comment: You can set initialScale for the WebView.

Comment: @greenapps This is set in meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">.

Comment: Yes i have seen that of course. But wouldn't you try it in a different way? For me it works. `webView.setInitialScale(150);`

Comment: did you get the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue and I solved liked below. first I check the device's density, according to the density, scaled the webView.

```
 float deviceDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     Log.i("device density", ""+deviceDensity);

     /**
      *  check the android version and if it is Lollipop or upper version then I scaled
      *  the webView according to the density
      */
     int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int scaleLevel = (int) (100 * deviceDensity);
             webView.setInitialScale(scaleLevel);
        }
```

I tested on Samsung S6 Edge and it worked perfectly.